# How to save changes in Angular UI-Grid when using cell template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm having trouble understanding where to begin when trying to save changes in a ui-grid cell template.When I went through the Ui-Grid tutorial all I found was how to save changes when there a single field mapped to a column: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable.

I created a simple grid as an example that has multiple input text fields in one column.  How would you approach editing and saving changes to this grid?  Using Kendo + razor + c# I was able to save changes in a column that had 8-9 variables in it.  I'm having trouble understanding how to do this with the angular ui-grid.

All in all, I'd like the use to click a single save button outside of the grid once he or she is done editing data in the grid.

Here's a link to my simple grid example: http://plnkr.co/edit/IeYWL62Oa182crRUEtX4?p=info

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      rowHeight: 40,
      enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
      enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = 
    [{ name: 'id', width: 35},
     { name: 'template',
       cellTemplate: '<div><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-input="row.entity.name" ng-model="row.entity.name" /></div>' + 
                     '<div><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-input="row.entity.age" ng-model="row.entity.age" /></div>' },
    ];

    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      });
  }
])
```

Comment: Create a function that accepts an object in your $scope , add a save button in your table row that binds the ng-click with function you just created, pass the row.entity into the function and save it. That's about it.

Comment: updating the question to include that I'd like a single save button outside of the grid save changes

Comment: Very simple too. Create two functions, one that will push the changed object into an array of changed objects, one that will save all objects. Bind ng-change on first function and place it on the correct fields passing row.entity. So when objects change you push them into the array of changed objects. When the users clicks save, you iterate over that array and save them one by one or all at once.

Comment: conceptually I understand what your saying but I think my knowledge of Angular (still a beginner here) is prohibiting me to test this on my own haha..  can you show me an example?  particularly regarding how to "..push the changed object into an array of changed objects" on the fly

Comment: Answered with an example. Shout if you need some additional explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very naive way without any checking. It is only to illustrate you **a** way of tackling your problem.

The following piece of code will keep track of the objects that have been changed in your table. Keep in mind no checking has been done, you still have to filter doubles, remove object where changes have been undone perhaps etc...

```
$scope.arrayOfChangedObjects = [];

$scope.objectHasChanged = function(object) {
    $scope.arrayOfChangedObjects.push(object);
};
```

Then a function to save.

```
$scope.save = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.arrayOfChangedObjects.length; i++) {
      //do the saving
  }
};
```

Adjusting your template to call those methods. Note the **grid.appScope.method()**!

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = 
[{ name: 'id', width: 35},
 { name: 'template',
   cellTemplate: '<div><input type="text" ng-change="grid.appScope.objectHasChanged(row.entity)" class="form-control" ng-input="row.entity.name" ng-model="row.entity.name" /></div>' + 
                 '<div><input type="text" ng-change="grid.appScope.objectHasChanged(row.entity)" class="form-control" ng-input="row.entity.age" ng-model="row.entity.age" /></div>' },
];
```

And ofcourse letting ui-grid know you're using the edit module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid','ui.grid.edit']);

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="save()">save</button>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-edit></div>
</div>
```

Working plunker can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fCwENYcdpOhlqjQFWWm6).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use their Edit Feature, you have to inject it into your module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);
```

then in your html, you do:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-edit></div>
```

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4rHz0wHPK0Gyzcx8b7rD?p=preview)

Comment: I saw an example like this when I was searching and it works except when you use their cell template functionality.  If you put name and age in a single column template how do I edit both? I started off with putting them both in separate input text fields but wasn't sure what the next best step was